# Python - Access the Temp-Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m trying to write a file into the %temp%-Folder, but the username of every User is different.

Does Python have a function or some kind like that to join the folder?
I tried it like this, but I get an Syntax Error, because Python can't decode it:

```
tmppath = "C:\Users\ %s \AppData\Local\Temp" %( os.getlogin() )
```

thx for help :)

Edit: The Error, in case it helps:

```
SyntaxError: (Unicode Error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in     
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Replace single backslashes by two.

Comment: Please don't do that when you have dedicated [tempfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) to help you deal with cross-platform support.

Comment: Thx for the fast help, it works. It rly was just the confusion with the backslashes ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace each `\` with `\\`. Also, you should use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of `%s%`:

```
import os
tmppath = "C:\\$SB52EF.tmpUsers\\{}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp".format(os.getlogin())
```

You might be interested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).